# Garbage Collection and local variables to whose events a control has subscribed

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

If a c# class declares a variable, say an ObservableCollection, and subsequently 
subscribes to an event on that variable, does that prevent the control from being garbage collected. In other words, in the following circumstance, is the class SomeClass available for garbage collection:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _someCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public SomeClass()
    {
        _someCollection.CollectionChanged += OnSomeCollectionCollectionChanged;
    }

    private void OnSomeCollectionCollectionChanged(object sender,NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e )
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming nothing else has a reference to the `ObservableCollection`, both of them will be eligible for garbage collection.

However, if something else keeps the `ObservableCollection` alive, the reference from the collection to the `SomeClass` instance (via the event) will keep the `SomeClass` object alive too.

EDIT: To clarify the comments... the GC is quite capable of collecting two object which refer to each other, so long as nothing else is referring to them. For example:

```
               /---->----\
  X ---->---- Y           Z
(root)         \----<----/
```

Here object "X" is acting as a root, i.e. it's something the garbage collector *knows* should be kept alive (e.g. it's referred to from a local variable in a stack from of thread, or it's referred to via a static variable).

Now imagine that the reference from X to Y is severed:

```
               /---->----\
  X           Y           Z
(root)         \----<----/
```

Now X is still kept alive as a GC root, but there are no "live" objects which refer to either Y or Z, so they can both be garbage collected. The fact that they refer to each other is irrelevant.

Comment: Can you explain this further please. Both items do have references (_someCollection is referenced by the SomeClass instance, and the SomeClass instance is referenced by the ObservableCollection instance inside the eventhandler). On my understanding neither should be available for garbage collection, or is there a special case here?

Comment: @Stephen: If they're just referring to each other, and nothing else is referring to *them*, then there'll be no "root" references. The .NET GC is quite capable of collecting cyclic references.

Comment: Jon. Thanks. Great answer. Now I'm beginning to understand GC roots. You say "e.g. it's referred to from a local variable in a stack from of thread, or it's referred to via a static variable."  Could you clarify the first circumstance? Are these the only circumstances that create GC root objects?

Comment: @Stephen: They're the only ones I can think of offhand, but there are probably others :) The first circumstance is: think of each thread, and any *reachable* local variables in any stack frame in each thread. If there's a chance we'll read that variable again, it's a GC root.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `O.E += Y` (where `E` is an event), object `O` will have a reference to `Y`. That means `Y` cannot be collected until it either unsubscribes or `O` gets collected. There is nothing to stop `O` from getting collected.

Comment: In my example, o is referenced by SomeClass, and SomeClass is referenced by o. By your logic, does this not mean neither is eligible for garbage collection?

Comment: @Stephen Ellis: Once `SomeClass` is eligible for GC, `o` is eligible for construction. Circular references do not prevent GC in .Net.