# Garbage collection of an object that is registered to an event

Tags: c#, .net, events, garbage-collection

I have view object that initializes another object, creditCard Object, and register to an event that the creditCard is raising. If the view object will have no reference to it. Will it be garbage collected? or do I have to unsubscribe in order for that to happen?

Comment: its not related to view object only. `creditCard` should have no reference anywhere in your program to be gc`ed

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103675/garbage-collection-and-local-variables-to-whose-events-a-control-has-subscribed, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507632/net-object-events-and-dispose-gc, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853300/in-c-do-events-keep-a-reference-to-the-entire-class-where-the-call-back-method, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372479/will-this-event-handler-code-cause-a-memory-leak, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428402/why-this-does-not-cause-a-memory-leak-when-event-is-not-unsubscribed, ...

Comment: ... and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370527/garbage-collection-of-unreferenced-object-with-live-event-handler

Comment: Note that your question as asked is too broad and unanswerable, because you haven't explained the lifetime of the `creditCard` object. As all of the other discussion on Stack Overflow explains, a subscriber to an event is referenced, which _may_ prevent it from being collected. But if the object with the event is itself not reachable, both the publisher and subscriber of the event can be collected. Without a good [mcve] illustrating your question, no one can tell you what you actually need to do. It just depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to unsubscribe for the object to be garbage collected.

*"The cause is simple to explain: while an event handler is subscribed, the publisher of the event holds a reference to the subscriber via the event handler delegate (assuming the delegate is an instance method)."* - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526840/283787

Answer (score 0):

When your `creditCard` object subscribes to event ti will reference your view object. For example `creditCard.Event += MyEvent...` and this is equivalent to `creditCard.Event += this.MyEvent...` where `this` will be referencing the`view` object so you have to unsubscribe in order to be garbage collected.